# change a inner html id with js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how do you change a inner id with js and keep it the same id num (e.g hey1, bob2)

my js code

```
var obj = document.getElementById("chat").cloneNode(true);
var obj1 = document.getElementById("ch");
var obj2 = document.getElementById("chatbox");

var p = $(".chat");
var offset = p.offset();

num = num + 1;        

if (num <=15) {

obj.id = obj.id + num;  <--- **changing the id (this one works fine but the other two dont**
obj1.id = obj1.id + num;   <--- changing the id
obj2.id = obj2.id + num;      <--- changing the id

document.body.appendChild(obj);
document.body.appendChild(obj1);
document.body.appendChild(obj2);

var left = offset.left + 275;

document.getElementById("chat").style.left = left + "px";
```

tell me if i am doing it wrong but this was the easiest way i thought off

(ps i am a beginner at javascript)

thanks to all that try to help...

**Edit**

ok i clone this

```
<div class="chat" id="chat">
<div id="ch" class="ch">
               <h2>Chat</h2></div>
               <div class="chatbox" id="chatbox">
               <div class="messages"></div>
               <textarea id="message" class="chatinp" 
               rows="3" cols="27"></textarea>
               <button class="send">Send</button></div>
</div>
```

and everytime it clones it changes the id of chat,ch and chatbox but keeping the original the same

like so...

**clone1**

```
<div class="chat" id="chat1">
<div id="ch1" class="ch">
               <h2>Chat</h2></div>
               <div class="chatbox" id="chatbox1">
               <div class="messages"></div>
               <textarea id="message" class="chatinp" 
               rows="3" cols="27"></textarea>
               <button class="send">Send</button></div>
</div>
```

**Clone2**

```
<div class="chat" id="chat2">
<div id="ch2" class="ch">
               <h2>Chat</h2></div>
               <div class="chatbox" id="chatbox2">
               <div class="messages"></div>
               <textarea id="message" class="chatinp" 
               rows="3" cols="27"></textarea>
               <button class="send">Send</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with *the other two don't (work)*? What does not work?

Comment: they just give me a error and this is the error uncaught typeerror: cannot read property 'id' of null

Comment: That means that `document.getElementById("ch")` and `document.getElementById("chatbox")` couldn't find the elements with that IDs. The problem is not in the two lines you marked, but in your HTML or in the lines which are supposed to retrieve the elements. That's why you should always include the actual error message in your question.

Comment: yer i figured that. But i what the script to keep the original but change the newer ones as i clone them

Comment: Not sure if I'm following... it seems there is no element with ID `ch`, that's why `document.getElementById("ch")` does not find it. You cannot clone an element that does not exist. You are wondering why `obj1.id + num` etc. "do not work" and the reason is that such elements don't exist. The solution is to assign that ID to an element or correct the ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, but if I'm right, you're trying to create a new 'chatnode'. You'll have to traverse the childNodes array of the node you cloned to change id's. Try something like:

```
function cloneChat(){
  var obj  = document.getElementById("chat").cloneNode(true),
      children = obj.childNodes
  ;
  num += 1;
  obj.id = obj.id+num;
  if (num<16){
      changeId(children,num);
  }
  //now appending obj to the document.body should be sufficient
  document.body.appendChild(obj);

  //change id recursively  
  function changeId(nodes, n){
   for (var i=0;i<nodes.length;i=i+1){
     if (nodes[i].childNodes){
           changeId(nodes[i].childNodes,n);
     }
     if(nodes[i].id && /^ch$|^chatbox$/i.test(nodes[i].id)) {
      nodes[i].id += String(n);
     }
   }
  }

}
```

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uHxZP/) for a working example

Furthermore, this code won't work:

```
var p = $(".chat");
var offset = p.offset();
```

Because `$(".chat")` returns a list of nodes, where every node has it's own offset.

You seem to be using jQuery, so I suggest adding a 'jQuery' tag to your question. Maybe some jQuery whizzkid has a solution to offer.

Comment: thanks but it doesn't change the chatbox and ch id well it does but only once.

Comment: also could you add some text so i can actually understand it?

Comment: You're right. See my edits and check the jsfiddle link for an update.

Comment: Forked the jsfiddle and adjusted the link in my answer. See the comments in the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery try to use

```
element.attr("id","newId");
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 0):

How about this function?

```
    function appendMe() {
        var elementsToClone = ["chat"];                       //Parent Elements to clone. This is the class name as well as the id
        var childrenToHandle = new Array();
        childrenToHandle["chat"] = ["ch"];          //Child elements mapping to keep sync. This is the class name as well as the id. Here we say that for the parent element chat, the inner elements to keep in sync is ch
        var itemCount = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < elementsToClone.length; i++) {
            var refObj = document.getElementById(elementsToClone[i]);
            if(refObj) {
                $("." + elementsToClone[i]).each(
                    function() {
                        if(this.id.match(/\d+$/g)) {
                            itemCount = this.id.match(/\d+$/g);
                        }
                    }
                );
                var newObj = refObj.cloneNode(true);
                newObj.id = elementsToClone[i] + ++itemCount;
                var childrenArray = childrenToHandle[elementsToClone[i]];
                if(childrenArray) {
                    $(childrenArray).each(
                        function() {
                            $(newObj).find("." + this).attr("id", this + itemCount);
                        }
                    );
                }
                document.body.appendChild(newObj);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using jQuery in your code, how about:

```
var $obj = $("#chat").clone(),
    $obj1 = obj.find("#ch"),
    $obj2 = obj.find("#chatbox");

var p = $(".chat"),
    offset = p.offset();

num = num + 1;

if (num <= 15) {

    $obj.attr('id', $obj.attr('id') + num);
    $obj1.attr('id', $obj1.attr('id') + num);
    $obj2.attr('id', $obj2.attr('id') + num);

    $('body').append(obj);

    var newLeft = offset.left + 275;

    $('#chat').css({
        left: newLeft
    });

}
```